# How to verify number of function evaluations when profiling R code

Tags: r, profiling

When profiling R code with Rprof-type functions we get the time spent in function alone and the time spent in function and callees. However, as far as I know we don't get the number of times a given function was evaluated.

For example, assume I wants to compare two integration functions:

```
integrate_1(myfunc, from = -Inf, to = Inf)
integrate_2(myfunc, from = -Inf, to Inf)
```

I could easily see how much time each function takes and where this time was spent, but I don't know how to check how many times myfunc had to be evaluated in each of the integrate functions.

Thanks,

Comment: A rather rough way would be to modify `myfunc` to increment a counter each time it is called. Probably using `assign`, since you'd most likely want the counter to exist in a separate environment that you have control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of implementing Joran's counter method is to use the `trace` function.

For example, first we set the counter to zero.  (Assigned in the global environment, for convenience.)

```
count <- 0
```

Then set up the trace.  Here we set it on the `identity` function (that just returns the value that you input to it).

```
trace("identity", quote(count <<- count + 1), print = FALSE)
```

Now whenever `identity` is called, the value of `count` is incremented.  `print = FALSE` just stops a message being printed to the console when the function is called.

Let's call the function a few times and inspect the count:

```
for(i in seq_len(123)) identity(1)
count
## [1] 123
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rprof` works by sampling the call stack on a timer. It does not count calls.

It records the sampled call stacks in a file, and though it does not record line numbers where calls occur, those samples are still useful for seeing what causes time to be spent.

For example, if you happen to look at M random samples, and you see a pattern like A calling B calling C on N of them, then you know the program spends roughly fraction N/M of its time doing that (assuming N > 1).
If you see such a thing, and you can think of a way to avoid even part of it, you will save a substantial fraction of the total time.

`Rprof` comes with a summarization tool that gives you the kind of numbers you mentioned, but I don't find those numbers useful anyway.
I would much rather get a real sense of what's happening.